# Can I pass a variable in Javascript to a child_process.exec command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I'm relatively new to Node and have been put on a project where the user will input their first and last name in a form, then the server will output a file with their first initial and their last name as the file name (so John Smith would come out as JSmith).

I'm trying to take that user input and put it in my [`child_process.exec`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) command, but it won't recognize the variable, so I'm getting a file with no name. So instead of `JSmith.txt`, I'm just getting `.txt`

```
var name = fields['name']
var nameArray = name.split(' ')
var fileName = nameArray[0].charAt(0) + nameArray[1]

process.exec("Start of my command here"+fileName+ ".txt", function(error, stdout, stderr){
    console.log('done')
    console.log('stdout:', stdout);
    console.log('stderr:', stderr);
})
```

Is this the right function to be using or should I use something else? I feel like the problem lies with the variable not being read incorrectly, but I don't know how to pass it in.

Comment: The command runs with space-separated arguments, check fileName variable, may be it is empty string =)

Comment: I'm sure, the problem is, that fields['name'] is already empty.

Comment: `fields['name']` isn't empty. It comes back with a value that is based on the input from the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into exactly your problem and my workaround included just concatenating the string in advance.

```
var name = fields['name']
var nameArray = name.split(' ')
var fileName = nameArray[0].charAt(0) + nameArray[1]
var command = yourCommand + filename + ".txt" #replace yourCommand here


process.exec(command, function(error, stdout, stderr){
    console.log('done')
    console.log('stdout:', stdout);
    console.log('stderr:', stderr);
})
```

In case you want to pass an object (eg. array) into another file via exec, you just need to stringify it first.

```
var myArray = ['beans', 'toast']
var stringifiedArray = JSON.stringify(myArray)
var command = 'python myModel.py ' + stringifiedArray


process.exec(command, function(error, stdout, stderr){
    console.log('done')
    console.log('stdout:', stdout);
    console.log('stderr:', stderr);
})
```

In the other file (in this case a python file called myModel.py), you can then parse the input again.

```
input = sys.argv[1]   #reading the (first) argument from the shell
data = json.loads(input)
```

Comment: Huge security issue if you don't have control on the input. Example `fields: { name: "; ls > rce-confirmed.txt" } is a simple proof of remote execution.